# WifiEsp client TIMEOUT when put on a loop

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, library

Hello I have been using the WifiEsp to send and receive data from Thingspeak.
All is well until I put my http request on the Void Loop() section.

My Goal: I want to receive data every loop not on only on setup.
Here is my code

```
#include <WiFiEsp.h>
#include <WiFiEspClient.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial Serial1(6, 7); // RX, TX
WiFiEspClient  client; 
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS; 

#define SSID "Benok4G"      
#define PASS "password"
char reply;
char server[] = "184.106.153.149";

void setup() {
// put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(115200);
Serial1.begin(9600);
WiFi.init(&Serial1);
while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
Serial.println(SSID);
// Connect to WPA/WPA2 network
status = WiFi.begin(SSID, PASS);
}
Serial.println("You're connected to the network");

}

void loop() {
Serial.println();
Serial.println("Receiving Data...");
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
Serial.println("Connected to server");
client.println("GET /channels/344468/fields/3/last?key=ABCDEFGH 
HTTP/1.1");
client.println("Host: api.thingspeak.com");
client.println("Connection: close");
client.println();

while (client.available()) {
char c = client.read();
Serial.write(c);     
}

if (!client.connected()) {
Serial.println();
Serial.println("Disconnecting from server...");
client.stop();
while(true);
 }
}
```

I can receive the letter "a" properly. However, I want it too loop and give me updated value every loop.

[image]

BUT! when I put the code from the void setup() to the the void loop(). 
I get this error..
[image]

Any ideas on how can I loop it without getting the error? I tried adding delays and putting it on another function, still the same. It will only work when I put in inside the void setup()

Thanks!

Comment: @MarkSmith Thank you for pointing that out. I have posted my complete code. The code i posted is when I put the request in the loop and gives the timeout error.

Comment: By "this error", do you mean the timeout? It looks to be working regardless... What's the actual problem?

Comment: When I put it in the loop.I don't see the picture with OK response. It's just blank and sometimes it returns the one with square. Is this normal?

Comment: Could it be that your setup() is taking too long to execute and is timing out?

Comment: "Host: api.thingspeak.com"  Some of the free services provided by Thingspeak prohibit multiple consecutive transactions unless there is an intervening  pause of X seconds which could cause the timeout you appear to be experiencing. Check the rules of your subscription.